# Connection to Microsoft SQL server error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Below is a concise version of my code as it pertains to db access.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DataAccess
{
   public class DbConnection
{
    public string connString = "Data Source=[Insert IP];Initial Catalog=MOSAIQ;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[Insert User];Password=[Insert Password]";

    public void CreateConnection()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For security reason I've removed IP and user credentials. That being said I copied the above connection string directly from the properties of the server explorer which successfully connected to my db.

While stepping through this code the following error is caught upon executing `conn.Open()`
[image]

Seems pretty obvious that there is an issue during validation. The credentials supplied are those used for SQL authentication.

Why is it that I *can* connect via server explorer but *not* directly via my code? What does Visual Studio's do for me that I can't seemingly do myself?

Ports are open, firewall is not an issue. I'm stumped and as a rookie in this matter would appreciate further guidance.

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2, using Visual Studio's 2013.

Comment: SQL Server what? Enterprise? Express? Compact?

Comment: This might help: http://ricardodsanchez.com/2012/04/05/how-to-configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/ but first make sure your SQL server is hosted under IP 1.1.1.1 - seems uncommon.

Comment: I agree with Ricardo, 1.1.1.1 seems awfully odd to me. When you log into it via SQL MGT Studio, do you enter 1.1.1.1? Enter whatever it is you enter there to log in. What about testing a ODBC connection? Does that work as well? (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC) -> Add -> Configure from there). Does that work ok with what you have in connection string?

Comment: He probably replaced the actual IP with 1.1.1.1 for security reasons. Since you are logging in with a user name and password, ensure the the server is set up to accept Windows authentication AND SQL authentication. If it is not, you will get an error when you try to connect.

Comment: That too- there's a plethora of "what it could be".

Comment: @ High Arch: Miscrosoft SQL Server 2008 R2. JRLambert is correct, the IP is not a series of 1's rather something more applicable but for security reasons I didn't see a need to include the actual IP. @Ricardo, I did check out that link and appreciate the feedback. However I do know that the SQL server is able to receive incoming traffic as stated above I'm able to accomplish the same goal using Java and a similarly formatted connection string. I've not had a chance to try Alykins recommendation. thank you again for the input.

Answer (score 0):

As a test try to use the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Data Source"] = "(local)";
builder["integrated Security"] = true;
//Or Supply User and Password
builder["Connect Timeout"] = 1000;
builder["Initial Catalog"] = "AdventureWorks;NewValue=Bad";
Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString);
```

If you do that and are still experiencing the error then move on to testing the networking.

```
<add name="RM_V1.0CS1" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=sa;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Edit Explicitly Set Provider:

Comment: Just for my own knowledge in learning C#, is the advantage of using the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class to ensure correct placement of strongly typed properties? Just trying to follow the logic that perhaps the way the current connection string is being parsed out maybe the issue? Typing out loud I guess then that would make sense that this class would try and alleviate that potential error.

Comment: When using 'SqlConnection' what is the default provider that is utilized? When I looked ad the advanced properties of my established connection using Server Explorer it is showing 'Provider=SQLNCLI11', I was hoping to check this as this isn't a field I can specify in my connection string while using 'SqlConnection'

Comment: @TargetofGravity Yes the builder should eliminate any bad parsing or typos.  After reading your comment I believe the issue is the provider.  Try Explicitly setting the provider providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  See Edit Above

Comment: A recent discovery is that although I've specified SQL credentials in my connection string, authentication on the SQL server side is using my windows credentials which is causing the failure. Does anyone know why this is occurring and where I can make the change?

Answer (score 0):

For those that might experience similar issues. I save my solutions on a network drive through work. Because I was opening and running my solution from this network location for a reason I'm yet unaware of it was using my windows credentials instead of the SQL credentials that I was passing to the SQL server. Once the solution was moved to my local workstation the method ran as expected. Any insight as to what more specifically was occurring would be of interest.